# How to modify json data in fiddler.

Tags: javascript, extjs, telerik, fiddler

I am gettring one issue so I want to change the day in fiddler,
which after ajax request I am getting this json data.

```
{
  "ROOT": {
   "DATA": {
      "I": [
        [
          "ABC",
          "123"
        ],
        [
          "DEF",
          "124"
        ],
        [
          "GHI",
          "125"
        ]

      ]
    }
}
}
```

Now in fiddler url I want to change this  like below.

```
{
  "ROOT": {
   "DATA": {
      "I": [

        [
          "DEF",
          "124"
        ],
        [
          "GHI",
          "125"
        ]

      ]
    }
}
}
```

Is there any way I can change data in fiddler by clicking on my url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Go to Fiddler, right click on the url and then go to Replay -> Reissue and Edit

Now on the right side go to Inspectors -> TextView. You will see the json data that you want to change. Do the changes and then click on Run To Completion to hit the same url with the CHANGED data.